# Customize Infowindow : move arrow to the left not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, infowindow

I'm using the "5 ways to customize the Google Maps Infowindow"
( code here : https://codepen.io/Marnoto/pen/xboPmG )

When clicking for the first time on the marker, the window opens, but the arrow don't move to the left (this appens not all the time, but very often).

Starting the second click, it's positioning correctly, as written in the JS :

```
// Moves the arrow 76px to the left margin.
iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});
```

Here is a pic of the problem
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e56Rm.jpg)

And here is a pic of how it works when the style property is correctly applied
[capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOrVM.jpg)

Is there a way to fix this ??

Thank you!

Edit : THIS IS THE CODE

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: none;
}
#map-canvas img {
    max-width: none !important;
}
.gm-style-iw {
    width: 350px !important;
    top: 15px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
    border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 10px 10px;
}
#iw-container {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#iw-container .iw-title {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #48b5e9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
#iw-container .iw-content {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
    max-height: 140px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.iw-content img {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 10px; 
}
.iw-subTitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.iw-bottom-gradient {
    position: absolute;
    width: 326px;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 18px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/*
 * 5 ways to customize the Google Maps infowindow
 * 2015 - en.marnoto.com
 * http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html
*/

// map center
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.589500, -8.683542);

// marker position
var factory = new google.maps.LatLng(40.589500, -8.683542);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: center,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

  // InfoWindow content
  var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                    '<div class="iw-title">Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">History</div>' +
                      '<img src="http://maps.marnoto.com/en/5wayscustomizeinfowindow/images/vistalegre.jpg" alt="Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre" height="115" width="83">' +
                      '<p>Founded in 1824, the Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre was the first industrial unit dedicated to porcelain production in Portugal. For the foundation and success of this risky industrial development was crucial the spirit of persistence of its founder, José Ferreira Pinto Basto. Leading figure in Portuguese society of the nineteenth century farm owner, daring dealer, wisely incorporated the liberal ideas of the century, having become "the first example of free enterprise" in Portugal.</p>' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">Contacts</div>' +
                      '<p>VISTA ALEGRE ATLANTIS, SA<br>3830-292 Ílhavo - Portugal<br>'+
                      '<br>Phone. +351 234 320 600<br>e-mail: geral@vaa.pt<br>www: www.myvistaalegre.com</p>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                  '</div>';

  // A new Info Window is created and set content
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content,

    // Assign a maximum value for the width of the infowindow allows
    // greater control over the various content elements
    maxWidth: 350
  });

  // marker options
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: factory,
    map: map,
    title:"Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre"
  });

  // This event expects a click on a marker
  // When this event is fired the Info Window is opened.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

  // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  // *
  // START INFOWINDOW CUSTOMIZE.
  // The google.maps.event.addListener() event expects
  // the creation of the infowindow HTML structure 'domready'
  // and before the opening of the infowindow, defined styles are applied.
  // *
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

    // Reference to the DIV that wraps the bottom of infowindow
    var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

    /* Since this div is in a position prior to .gm-div style-iw.
     * We use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
     * and took advantage of the existing reference .gm-style-iw for the previous div with .prev().
    */
    var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

    // Removes background shadow DIV
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

    // Removes white background DIV
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

    // Moves the infowindow 115px to the right.
    iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '115px'});

    // Moves the shadow of the arrow 76px to the left margin.
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

    // Moves the arrow 76px to the left margin.
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

    // Changes the desired tail shadow color.
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6) 0px 1px 6px', 'z-index' : '1'});

    // Reference to the div that groups the close button elements.
    var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

    // Apply the desired effect to the close button
    iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});

    // If the content of infowindow not exceed the set maximum height, then the gradient is removed.
    if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
      $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
    }

    // The API automatically applies 0.7 opacity to the button after the mouseout event. This function reverses this event to the desired value.
    iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
      $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Can you post your code please? Otherwise I can't give you a solution

Comment: Ok, I edited with the code, exactly same as : codepen.io/Marnoto/pen/xboPmG

Answer (score 0):

try the pixelOffset for the infowindow

for example: I moved my whole infowindow to the right of the marker:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: $marker.html(),
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(175, 114),
    maxWidth: '290',
  });
```

the pixelOffset equals half of my maxWidth and double the height of my marker icon

then I also changed this line:

```
// Moves the infowindow to the right.
    iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '0px', top: '0px'});
```

so the top left corner will be aligned to the right of the marker icon and in the CSS:

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw{
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I also exchanged the arrow thingy - adding an additional div inside my marker-wrap, which has the following style:

```
.marker-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  height: 24px;
}
```

in addition I changed the styles for the arrow, so it doesn't appear anywhere visibly:

```
// Moves the shadow of the arrow to the left.
iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 0px !important; top: 0px !important;'});

// Moves the arrow to the left.
iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 0px !important; top: 0px !important;'});

// Changes the desired tail shadow color.
iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'unset', 'z-index' : '0', 'background' : 'transparent'});
```

hope that helps ;-)